# I want to populate my model with json in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my `RequestClass`:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Common.Domain.ValueObjects;

namespace Common.Domain.Entitites.Request;

public class AddSkillRequest
{
    public AddSkillRequest(
          Guid skillId,
          JsonDocument? skillName,
          string skillCode,
          JsonDocument? icon,
          JsonDocument? thumbnail,
          JsonDocument? image,
          int? displayOrder,
          bool? isActive,
          DateTime createdAt,
          Guid createdBy,
          DateTime updatedAt,
          Guid updatedBy)
    {
        SkillId = skillId;
        SkillName = skillName;
        SkillCode = SkillCode.Create(skillCode);
        Icon = icon;
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
        Image = image;
        DisplayOrder = displayOrder;
        IsActive = isActive;
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
        UpdatedAt = updatedAt;
        UpdatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Guid SkillId { get; private set; }
    public JsonDocument? SkillName { get; private set; }
    public SkillCode? SkillCode { get; private set; }
    public JsonDocument? Icon { get; set; }
    public JsonDocument? Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public JsonDocument? Image { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; private set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

This is my endpoint:

```
    group_v1.MapPost("/addSkill", async ([FromBody]AddSkillRequest request, ISender sender) => Results.Ok(await sender.Send(new AddSkillsCommand(request))));
```

When I am sending this payload

```
{
    "SkillId":"458de859-c021-4188-915e-12b1fdbaae45",
  "SkillName": {  
    "name":"abcd"
  },
  "SkillCode": "EL",
  
    "Icon": {
      "low": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "medium": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "high": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      }
    },
    "Thumbnail": {
      "low": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "Medium": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "High": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      }
    },
    "Image": {
      "low": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "medium": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      },
      "high": {
        "publicUrl": "",
        "publicShortUrl": "",
        "dimension": ""
      }
    },
  "displayOrder": 1,
  "isActive": true,
  "CreatedAt": "2024-03-28T10:00:00Z",
  "CreatedBy": "08e56d49-6e06-41ac-950a-15d17f34608c",
  "UpdatedAt": "2024-03-28T10:00:00Z",
  "UpdatedBy": "a5fcb847-7d4b-4d15-9076-cd9fe4ad18b4"
}
```

I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Common.Domain.Entitites.Request.AddSkillRequest' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.

Please help me solve it

i used postgresql for as database where some of my datatype is jsonb

Answer (score 0):

You get the error due to the `JsonDeserializer` uses the constructor in your `AddSkillRequest` class and the sent JSON request doesn't match the parameters for the constructor.

[Parameterized constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability#parameterized-constructors)

> For a class, if the only constructor is a parameterized one, that constructor will be used.

You need to define a constructor that matches your JSON request body parameters for the deserialization with the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute.

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class AddSkillRequest
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public AddSkillRequest(
          JsonDocument? icon,
          JsonDocument? thumbnail,
          JsonDocument? image,
          int? displayOrder,
          bool? isActive,
          DateTime createdAt,
          Guid createdBy,
          DateTime updatedAt,
          Guid updatedBy)
    {
        Icon = icon;
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
        Image = image;
        DisplayOrder = displayOrder;
        IsActive = isActive;
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
        UpdatedAt = updatedAt;
        UpdatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTlJAD)